# Paypal for a buy/sell website

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, paypal

So I'm working on this website where users post their items, other users add some items to their cart and purchase them online.

The flow i was thinking about goes like this:

1. A merchant posts an item along with their credit cart/ paypal information.
2. A buyer adds items (from different merchants) to his/her shopping cart and purchases.
3. The buyer pays by filling a form that includes the payment method fields within the website's layout (no redirection to paypal).
4. The website will work as a gateway, it will capture the payments from the buyers and pays the merchants accordingly and automatically.

Is this possible using PayPal? if so, what API should I use?
Any input/idea is appreciated...

Thanks,
/t

Answer (score 2):

I have also investigated using PayPal in this way for a site with a similar concept. Unfortunately, PayPal does not allow this. This makes you something known as a Third Party Payment Aggregator which drastically increases the risk associated with providing you a Merchant Account (which is what PayPal is doing). You can read more [here](http://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/high-risk-mechant-account-third-party-payments-aggregation).

Though, you could probably do it for a while before PayPal caught on, they could cancel at anytime leaving you high and dry. I recommend investigating Third Party Payment Aggregator solutions ([Braintree](http://www.braintreepayments.com) has something that helps with this).

Answer (score -1):

I guess it is. Use Paypal API

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference

https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: Well, I came to this website because I couldn't get enough from the paypal documentation, after reading their API I still did not get a grip of how this could be applied to my problem. the link you posted is broken, if stackoverflow had a "hundred points minus rate" option i'd go for it.